# converting file from .txt to .csv doesn't write last column of data

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file that I'm trying to convert to a .csv file and have all the data separated into columns at every instance where there is white space between characters. The following code is doing this however it isn't writing the last column of data.

```
txt_file = r'ATF_160A_AR-160B_Pr_Temp_test.txt'
data = []
with open(txt_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([word for word in line.split(' ') if word])


csv_file = r'ATF_160A_AR-160B_Pr_Temp_test.csv'
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))


out_csv.writerows(data)
```

The text file looks like this.

```
odbName stepName instanceName  setName tmax_F tmax_C xcoord
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.345 420.747 0.0
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 751.559 399.755 0.1244
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.300 420.722 0.004976
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.193 420.663 0.009952
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.017 420.565 0.014928
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 788.770 420.428 0.019904
```

Comment: Could you show a few records of the input data if it's not too sensitive to do so?

Comment: See the original question. I've edited it to show a portion of the text file. It is deleting all of the xcoord column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the sample input data to it.

Comment: And each row has an entry for each column? In other words, there isn't a situation where perhaps tmax_F is missing for a record and everything gets shifted over one column...

Comment: No there isn't. the txt file is actually an extraction of data that happens earlier in my python script and when I open up the txt file and look at it everything looks fine. I even copied and pasted the txt file into excel and did the text-to-columns feature to separate to ensure it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
txt_file = r'ATF_160A_AR-160B_Pr_Temp_test.txt'
csv_file = r'ATF_160A_AR-160B_Pr_Temp_test.csv'
with open(txt_file) as infile, open(csv_file, 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(row.split() for row in infile)
```

## Discussion

1. Call `split()` without any argument to do the right thing: split by spaces, even multiple spaces
2. If your input file is large, you should not put them into a list (`data`), but process each line and write, which makes it faster and require less memory.

## Update

Try this to see if you can eliminate blank rows:

```
    writer.writerows(row.split() for row in infile if row.strip())
```

## Update 2

Let's try again with Pat Jones' suggestion (I think he meant to strip first, thens split):

```
    writer.writerows(row.strip().split() for row in infile if row.strip())
```

Comment: That worked other than it put an extra blank row between rows.

Comment: Please see my update. My machine is Mac, not Windows, so if it does not work, I suspect it has to do with line ending handling. Please let me know.

Comment: Still has the blank rows between each row.

Comment: Strange. I tried it with your block of data and it works just fine. Do you have a different block of data which shows this problem? Please update your post with it.

Comment: I think that `row.split()` needs to be `row.split().strip()`. See my answer, there are new line characters appended to the entries in the last column.

Comment: Thank you, @PatJones. I updated my post with update 2

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code on the input data that you presented, but put a couple of print statements in to see what it is doing, I noticed newline characters on the entries in the last column:

```
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '789.345', '420.747', '0.0\n']
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '751.559', '399.755', '0.1244\n']
```

I'd probably strip those off before writing out, because they can often times have unforeseen impacts:

```
data.append([word.strip('\n') for word in line.split(' ') if word])
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc for csv.writer say that if the target is an opened file, it should be opened with `newline=''`.  I am pretty sure it should not be opened in binary (bytes) mode.  The following code, coded for development (without using external files),

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

f = '''\
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.345 420.747 0.0
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 751.559 399.755 0.1244
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.300 420.722 0.004976
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.193 420.663 0.009952
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 789.017 420.565 0.014928
abcd-1_AB.odb Nominal SPECIMEN_POS1-1 SET-1 788.770 420.428 0.019904
'''.splitlines()

data = []
for line in f:
     data.append([word for word in line.split(' ') if word])
for line in data: print(line)

out = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(out)
writer.writerows(data)
for line in out.getvalue().splitlines(): print(line)
```

prints

```
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '789.345', '420.747', '0.0']
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '751.559', '399.755', '0.1244']
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '789.300', '420.722', '0.004976']
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '789.193', '420.663', '0.009952']
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '789.017', '420.565', '0.014928']
['abcd-1_AB.odb', 'Nominal', 'SPECIMEN_POS1-1', 'SET-1', '788.770', '420.428', '0.019904']
abcd-1_AB.odb,Nominal,SPECIMEN_POS1-1,SET-1,789.345,420.747,0.0
abcd-1_AB.odb,Nominal,SPECIMEN_POS1-1,SET-1,751.559,399.755,0.1244
abcd-1_AB.odb,Nominal,SPECIMEN_POS1-1,SET-1,789.300,420.722,0.004976
abcd-1_AB.odb,Nominal,SPECIMEN_POS1-1,SET-1,789.193,420.663,0.009952
abcd-1_AB.odb,Nominal,SPECIMEN_POS1-1,SET-1,789.017,420.565,0.014928
abcd-1_AB.odb,Nominal,SPECIMEN_POS1-1,SET-1,788.770,420.428,0.019904
```

With a target expecting strings rather than bytes, the writer writes all fields.

If you know that your input file never contains ',', you can skip using csv and create the output lines with `','.join(word for word in line.split(' '))` and write them with `outfile.write`.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, after adding `import csv` and replacing `line.split(' ')` by `line.strip().split(' ')` as suggested by others, your script runs as expected.

There are at least 3 steps involved:

- splitting the line
- inserting entries into data list
- printing csv

Find out which step fails, for example by extending your script as follows:

```
import csv    
txt_file = r'ATF_160A_AR-160B_Pr_Temp_test.txt'
data = []
with open(txt_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
        for word in line.strip().split(' '):
            print bool(word), ": ", word
        data.append([word for word in line.strip().split(' ') if word])
        print data

csv_file = r'ATF_160A_AR-160B_Pr_Temp_test.csv'
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))

out_csv.writerows(data)
```

Which step does not produce the expected output in your case?